# threads and bucles in c# (Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I am working with a third party library which uses a function that returns a message string. My problem is I do not know at what point will receive this message and I need to build an application in C# that shows the message in a textbox.

Note: I can receive 'n' messages while the program is running.

According to what I read is that I need to use threads, but not how.

I tried to do this but did not get the desired result:

```
Thread p1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(myfuntion));
p1.Start();

public myfunction()
{
    while (true)
    {
        textbox.text = myobj.messages;
    }
}
```

Help please!

Comment: what kind of library is that? isn't there an event that notifies you of the changed message? if not, you need to set up a [`Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) that checks for a new message every few seconds *(hint: endless loops are not the way).*

Comment: Can't understand your question ,can you be more clear , How about using events when a new message is released it's subscriber are informed about it ?

Comment: @lvanrlg What's `bucles` I have heard it first time ?

Comment: This isn't enough information to be able to answer your question.

If the third-party library delivers messages to you asynchronously, it will presumably have let you provide it with a callback function which will get hit when a message arrives. You shouldn't need to start a separate thread unless you need to poll for new messages, which seems unlikely given what you've said.

Comment: @dotNetSoldier Sorry for my bad English, I am using google translator, I meant loop not bucle.

Comment: I'm working on an interface of a digital mobile radio system and I have a library that when I receive a message from the mobile radio runs the following function
'public delegate void TMR(ushort code, byte* Payload, uint Size, uint LocalIP);'
through the parameter Payload I get the message. within the delegate put a messagebox and I received the message perfectly.
then I keep in my class that message in a string and then from my main function (windows form) to show through a textbox the message received and I will receive a batch of messages.

Comment: Viewed another way, in the invocation of the delegate I could be saved in a database messages, now the problem would be to make repetitive queries at certain intervals of time to show the messages are saved

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use `Task` and you must use `Invoke` since you can't update the GUI from another thread.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(myfunction);

public void myfunction()
{
    while (true)
    {
        textBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox1.Text = myobj.messages));
    }
}
```

However, I'm not really satisfied with this code. This code is updating the gui always. You might want to wait between each iteration with `Thread.Sleep(milliseconds)` or use something in the library that send you a message when there is one without you have to check it yourself.

Comment: I threw this error:Error 1 Using the generic type type ('System.Action <T>') requires 1 type arguments

Comment: You need to use System.Action, not System.Action<T>. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I like to use BackGroundWorker. Threads will still cause a lock, as the thread will spawn from the Form itself.

```
 private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do not access the form's BackgroundWorker reference directly.
        // Instead use the reference provided by the sender parameter
        BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        // Extract the argument
        RequestEntity arg = (RequestEntity)e.Argument;

        // Start the time consuming operation
        Poll poll = new Poll();
        e.Result = poll.pollandgetresult(bw, arg);

        // If operation was cancelled by user
        if (bw.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

Nice article on Code Project as well....
[Read](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20627/BackgroundWorker-Threads-and-Supporting-Cancel)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a Form, you can use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` with certain interval.

```cs
private void StartPollingMessage()
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer myTimer = new Timer();
    myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(myTimer_Tick);
    myTimer.Interval = 200;
    myTimer.Start();
}

void myTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = myobj.messages;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void Main()
{
    //this is the line when you start calling the external method
    Parallel.Invoke(() => YourMethod);
}

public void YourMethod()
{
    string s = ExternalMethod();
    //now you can use BackgroundWorker to update the UI or do the same thing as @Amiram Korach suggested
}

public string ExternalMethod()
{
    Thread.Sleep(10000); // the operation to retrieve the string can take 1 hour for example
    return "String that you want to retrieve";
}

// Define other methods and classes here
```

Comment: You can use Parrallel if the order of the elements that you will receive is not relevant